# FastAPI User Auth Hardering Login Expire and Concurrent Session

Tags: python, rest, authentication, jwt, fastapi

I would like to prevent concurrent session per user account. Also I want to make log out users if user afk.

- I store cookie's on redis and cookie has it own usernames. Maybe I can
  decode all cookies and I can check all usernames for is exists on redis or not. IDK is it best practise? When there are many cookies on redis, does calculation take long?
- For make user log out while user is AFK, maybe i can store user activi on mongo or something else then I can check last activity.

I need suggest for best way to do these. What is the best practise?

Answer (score 0):

for the logging out, you can create a table in your database called JWTBlacklist when you store tokens when the user logs out, so you prevent the token to be used again by the user himself or to be stolen by checking if it exists in the table, even if it did not expire yet.
For preventing concurrent session per user account, you can associate the user acccount with UUID and then check Redis to prevent it from logging in again.
I advice you to read more about JWT and how they are handled, their pros and cos.